# How to setup proxy for external api in express.js

Tags: express, axios, http-proxy

While there are packages like `http-proxy-middleware` to config proxy for a client request, is there any way to config proxy for a dependent external api call in express.js? We are using `axios` to make the http call.

I don't want to proxy any endpoints that are exposed to the client, but in my express server I need to call some external api in order to reply to client. I want to be able to **optionally** proxy this external api to a separate mock server for testing purpose.
For instance, if my real dependent api is `realserver/foo/api/`, I want to switch it to `mockserver/foo/api` when necessary (s.a. using an environment variable).

What's more, because there is going to be a lot of different requests to be mocked (since each endpoint can take different parameters), I want my mock server to be able to call the real server to get a real response and store the real response so that I don't need to manage the mock response manually.

I know it's possible to do two endpoint mappings, e.g. on the real server do a mapping of mocked server endpoints and use it optionally. On the mock server, do a (reverse) mapping of real server endpoint. But I wonder whether this setup can be simplified using a proxy on `axios`?

Comment: This is not about proxying, just use an environment variable when constructing the URL: ``https.get(`https://${process.env.APISERVER}/foo/api`, ...)``.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen you're right but I didn't make the question clearer, have updated the question with a bit more background.